# Setting permission to a folder created by user

Tags: permissions

How can an end user set a permission on a folder which he has created in SharePoint 2013? Which permission level does he need, and how can he give the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to select the folder , Click on callout(...) --> Click **Shared With** -->**Advanced**--> Then break inheritance and click **Grant Permission** to give permission to users..
See this [blog](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-set-unique-permissions-for-folders-and-documents/) for more details.

The user must have at least **Full Control** permission or create custom permission level having "**Manage Permissions**".